# NameError in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

So I'm trying out the Public Activity gem for a notification timeline and I don't understand why I'm getting the NameError , uninitialized constant message.
Here's the error I'm getting:

```
NameError in ActivitiesController#index
uninitialized constant ActivitiesController::PublicActivity

app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

uninitialized constant ActivitiesController::PublicActivity

Here's my controller code where the error is said to be:

```
    class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
      def index
       @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
      end
     end
```

I'm trying this out based on a rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity 
And as far as I know I've done the same thing as the one on it.

There isn't any activity model, but here's the post and comments model where I used the PublicActivity module:

POST MODEL:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked
```

COMMENT MODEL

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PublicActivity::Model
tracked

belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of your `Activity` Model? Is it namespaced under a `PublicActivity` module?

Answer (score 1):

according to gem sources

```
 def load_orm
      require "public_activity/orm/#{@@orm.to_s}"
      m = "PublicActivity::ORM::#{@@orm.to_s.classify}".constantize
      ::PublicActivity.const_set(:Activity,  m.const_get(:Activity))
      ::PublicActivity.const_set(:Adapter,   m.const_get(:Adapter))
      ::PublicActivity.const_set(:Activist,  m.const_get(:Activist))
      ::PublicActivity.const_set(:Trackable, m.const_get(:Trackable))
    end
```

You should use next code

```
  @activities = ::PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
```

Also ensure that you installed gem with bundle, check `bundle show public_activity`